# fopen(); "Remote host file access not accepted" on a local file?

Tags: php, fopen

I am using the Tcpdf module and PHP to create dymanic PDF invoices from an ordering system.

The script should then save the invoice into a folder called "invoices". The folder exists, and there are full permissions for "everyone" (Windows).

The code I am using is this:

```
$pdf->Output('invoices/Delivery Note.pdf', 'F');
```

This uses fopen to save the file.

However the error I am getting is: `Warning: fopen(): remote host file access not supported, file://invoices/Delivery Note.pdf`

This is a local file, not a remote one.

I attempted adding a / prefix like this:

```
$pdf->Output('/invoices/Delivery Note.pdf', 'F');
```

but then I get this error instead: `Warning: fopen(file:///invoices/Delivery Note.pdf): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

I created the file, and left it empty, but the same error as above.

Does anyone know why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

From php-Script you can use:

```
$pdf->Output(__DIR__ . '/invoices/Delivery Note.pdf', 'F');
```

Comment: this is a better answer than the one selected as it will be still working after updating TCPDF. Thanks!

Comment: Whilst I agree that commenting out the code in tcpdf_static.php is a bad idea, I would argue that specifying the output location relative to DOCUMENT_ROOT is a better idea than specifying the output location relative to the location of the script that is running. Not much in it though I guess.

Answer (score 9):

After upgrading to the tcpdf 6.2.6 in vtiger 6.2 I've had the same problem, sending e-mail with pdf.

So I have changed the file:

```
 libraries/tcpdf/include/tcpdf_static.php
```

I have **commented** the code in fopenLocal() and changed the line

```
 fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$filename, $mode);
```

see:

```
  /**
         * Wrapper to use fopen only with local files
         * @param filename (string) Name of the file to open
         * @param $mode (string) 
         * @return Returns a file pointer resource on success, or FALSE on error.  
         * @public static
         */
        public static function fopenLocal($filename, $mode) {
    //      if (strpos($filename, '://') === false) {
    //          $filename = 'file://'.$filename;
    //      } elseif (strpos($filename, 'file://') !== 0) {
    //          return false;
    //      }
            return fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$filename, $mode);
        }
```

After changing this, it worked.

Comment: You do not need to comment out the code in tcpdf_static.php because providing a file name with an absolute path name, which DOCUMENT_ROOT will give you, is all that is needed.

Comment: Working solution!

Comment: Save my day 2 years later! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

similar to `user1007017`, but just comment the line like shown below (tcpdf 6.2.11)

```
public static function fopenLocal($filename, $mode) {
        if (strpos($filename, '://') === false) {
            //$filename = 'file://'.$filename;
        } elseif (stream_is_local($filename) !== true) {
            return false;
        }
        return fopen($filename, $mode);
    }
```

Comment: You sir are a life saver even after all these years! I have spent hours trying to figure this issue out. Your solution works perfectly. Had to also use @gerd solution of __DIR__ . but now working...

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using the following as Gerd has also suggested but make sure you use an absolute path:

`$pdf->Output(__DIR__ . '/invoices/Delivery Note.pdf', 'F');`

The path must be an absolute path & not a relative path. This PHP bug report explains why: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=28820

> The reason relative paths are not supported with the file:// wrapper comes down to a compromise in how UNC paths are dealt with (and more specifically how / are fuzzily interpreted as \ for windows installations).
>
> For Example:
>
> file://foo/bar
>
> Could be interpreted as a relative URI:  foo/bar  from the current working directory, OR it could be interpreted as a UNC:  \foo\bar  (share `bar` on computer `foo`).
>
> **For this and a few internal reasons the file:// wrapper is limited to absolute paths when called explicitly.**  For relative paths either use realpath() {as you did in your report}, or omit the explicit naming of the file wrapper.

You can then avoid modifying the TCPDF code and worrying about any upgrades replacing your modified code.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue was that the path for fopen has to be from the document root, and not from the PHP script location.

`C:\Website\www\script\invoice\invoice.pdf`

For example if the PHP script is inside the "script" folder, and you want to create the pdf inside the "invoice" folder, the script needs to have "\script\invoice\invoice.pdf".

Answer (score 0):

In prestashop you can do it in this way     $pdf->Output(_PS_ROOT_DIR_.'/modules/xxx/ticket.pdf', 'F');

Answer (score 0):

you can use this script

'$'pdf->Output(dirname(**FILE**,2). '/invoices/Delivery Note.pdf', 'F');

Comment: $pdf->Output(dirname(__FILE__,2). '/invoices/Delivery Note.pdf', 'F');

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
$pdf->Output($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/invoices/Delivery Note.pdf', 'F');
```

Comment: Still the same error: `Warning: fopen(file://E:/Websites/*******/www/invoices/Delivery Note.pdf): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

Comment: echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/invoices/Delivery Note.pdf' then hit printed url in your window explorer and check you get file or not.

Comment: I also used touch() with the same path to create an empty file, it works, but fopen can't access it still

Comment: I tried this way before reading this post and it doesn't work