# PHP: Saving File Above Root - fopen(): remote host file access not supported

Tags: php, fopen, tcpdf

I am trying to store PDF generated by tcpdf in "uploaded_files" but getting error. I checked [existing answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28853871/fopen-remote-host-file-access-not-accepted-on-a-local-file) but they have path inside webroot. In my situation path is above root.

```
$pdf->Output("../../uploaded_files/".'Temp.pdf', 'F');
```

> Message: fopen(): remote host file access not supported

Following are path details:

```
Web Root Path:/var/www/html/index.php
Upload Folder Path: /var/uploaded_files/
```

Permissions for both directories & files are 0777

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use absolute file paths not relative file paths. Try something like

```
$pdf->Output("/var/uploaded_files/".'Temp.pdf', 'F');
```

Or

```
$pdf->Output(__DIR__ . "../../uploaded_files/".'Temp.pdf', 'F');
```

Comment: Finally it worked after appending $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] to the path.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is related to file/directory permissions. Just for checking purposes make the access level of `/var/uploaded_files` to `777` and change owner to apache user of the directory `/var/uploaded_files` and then try to save file. If succeeds then adjust the permission as per your requirements. I suggest not to go with this approach because allowing Apache to access file system other than webroot is actually pretty dangerous.

Comment: I have already checked permissions, there is no permissions issue. I am using this approach to keep users files in safe place. I didnot find anyother solution for files safe keeping.

Comment: Did you go through the ownership of that folder? And what you can do is to use .htaccess to restrict the access of those user's files within the webroot.

Comment: Yes I can upload & delete files in these folders. .htaccess only prevents directory listing. When a file is rendered & user can get path of that file he can access that file so .htaccess is useless in this regard.

Comment: Can you run `ls -lh`in /var and paste the output?

Comment: @MyO apache runs php as a child process. That means that php only has permissions to those in group `http`. There is actually no other explanation. @codvlpr gave the correct answer. If you run php script from terminal, you can see that you can upload file anywhere. This is not a php question but more of apache and directory permissions